# how to convert this query in eloquent?

Tags: php, laravel

I am a beginner laravel developer who wants to convert this query into an eloquent ORM. I know eloquent make it small. I search a lot but was always stuck in where condition It working perfectly but need to change in eloquent.

```
Product::join('subcategories', 'subcategories.id', '=', 
'products.subcategory_id')
->join('categories', 'categories.id', '=', 'products.category_id')
->WHERE('products.name', 'like', '%' . $search . '%')
->orWHERE('subcategories.name', 'like', '%' . $search . '%')
->orWHERE('categories.name', 'like', '%' . $search . '%')
->orWHERE('products.description', 'like', '%' . $search . '%')
->orWHERE('products.price','=', $search)
->select('products.*')
->paginate(5);
```

In the second query, I want to select User where the role is admin but id not equal to 1.
User::where(['role'=>admin, 'id',!=,1])->first();
I am using this please guide me
User::where('role',admin)->where('id',!=,1)->first();

Comment: please provide your table names

Comment: Did you see some error ? Your query seem correct

Comment: You are making some basic typo errors. You have referenced ```userdetails``` and ```userdetail```. Also in the image provided you specified ```product_name``` not ```productname```. See this [working fiddle](https://implode.io/KOCOq1) of your code.